getting error - Formatter failed. See :ConformInfo for details
I want this to format my document on save, and I think the code will do that functionality wise - well it is not working is a different thing. When I try to save a file, I get an error saying Formatter failed. See :ConformInfo for details and when I do :ConformInfo I get the below output

I tried going through the debugging doc, but I am unable to understand how to proceed with it.
Here is my config for conform.nvim
return {
  'stevearc/conform.nvim',
  event = { 'BufReadPre', 'BufNewFile' },
  config = function()
    local conform = require 'conform'

    conform.setup {
      formatters_by_ft = {
        lua = { 'stylua' },
        svelte = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        -- astro = { { "prettierd", "prettier", stop_after_first = true } },
        javascript = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        typescript = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        javascriptreact = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        typescriptreact = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        json = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        graphql = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        -- java = { "google-java-format" },
        -- kotlin = { "ktlint" },
        -- ruby = { "standardrb" },
        markdown = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        erb = { 'htmlbeautifier' },
        html = { 'htmlbeautifier' },
        bash = { 'beautysh' },
        -- proto = { "buf" },
        -- rust = { "rustfmt" },
        yaml = { 'yamlfix' },
        toml = { 'taplo' },
        css = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        scss = { 'prettierd', 'prettier', stop_after_first = true },
        sh = { 'shellcheck' },
        go = { 'gofmt' },
      },
      format_on_save = {
        -- These options will be passed to conform.format()
        timeout_ms = 500,
        lsp_format = 'fallback',
      },
    }

    vim.keymap.set({ 'n', 'v' }, '<leader>pf', function()
      conform.format {
        lsp_fallback = true,
        async = false,
        timeout_ms = 1000,
      }
    end, { desc = 'Format file or range (in visual mode)' })
  end,
}

I am not sure, but I think my linter could also play a part (tell me if wrong)
Config for nvim-lint
return {
  'mfussenegger/nvim-lint',
  event = {
    'BufReadPre',
    'BufNewFile',
  },
  config = function()
    local lint = require 'lint'

    lint.linters_by_ft = {
      javascript = { 'eslint_d' },
      typescript = { 'eslint_d' },
      javascriptreact = { 'eslint_d' },
      typescriptreact = { 'eslint_d' },
      svelte = { 'eslint_d' },
      -- kotlin = { "ktlint" },
      -- terraform = { "tflint" },
      -- ruby = { "standardrb" },
    }

    lint.linters.eslint_d = require('lint.util').wrap(lint.linters.eslint_d, function(diagnostic)
      -- try to ignore "No ESLint configuration found" error
      -- if diagnostic.message:find("Error: No ESLint configuration found") then -- old version
      -- update: 20240814, following is working
      if diagnostic.message:find 'Error: Could not find config file' then
        return nil
      end
      return diagnostic
    end)

    local lint_augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('lint', { clear = true })

    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufEnter', 'BufWritePost', 'InsertLeave' }, {
      group = lint_augroup,
      callback = function()
        lint.try_lint()
      end,
    })

    vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ll', function()
      lint.try_lint()
    end, { desc = 'Trigger linting for current file' })
  end,
}


Please post the actual info text, not a screenshot
